# String splitting in Scala without discarding trailing empty strings

Tags: string, scala, split

Scala's splitting strings **by character** function discards trailing empty strings. For example `"1,2,3,,,".split(',')` results in `Array("1", "2", "3")`.

Is there a built-in method to split strings **by character** in Scala which keeps those, so that the result would be `Array("1", "2", "3", "", "", "")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass a string as the first parameter `","` then you can specify `-1` as the second parameter to return the empty matches as well.

```
"1,2,3,,,".split(",", -1)
```

Output

```
res0: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3, "", "", "")
```

Comment: ok, actually after testing: if escaped properly this function is not slower than splitting by character